# derivative of some function

Tags: calculus

I have the following function :

$$f_{x}\left(x,s\left(x,z\left(x\right)\right)\right)$$

When I try to differentiate it according to $x$, I find something but I am not sure :

$$f_{xx}+f_{xs}s_{x}+f_{xs}z_{x}\left(x\right)$$

Am I right ?

Comment: I recommend the notation $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ for this type of chain rule. It helps me, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should be

$$f_{xx}+f_{xs}s_{x}+f_{xs}s_zz_{x}\left(x\right)$$

Since $s$ is a function of $(x,z)$